# I want to create a Semi circle around imageView in Android. Can any one help me in it?

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, android-drawable

Can any please help me to create a drawable which create a semi circle around imageView?

[image: one]

I tried using clip drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <clip
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:clipOrientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="bottom"
     android:drawable="@color/cardview_dark_background"
     >
     <shape android:shape="oval" android:thickness="10dp">
         <solid android:color="#444"/>
     </shape>
 </clip>
```

Comment: You will need to create a custom view and draw a Path.

Comment: Thank you @cyroxis.